# Mount ISO changes owner to nobody

Tags: mount, iso

I can mount without problems all kind of ISOS with the `mount` command, to a `/tmp` directory:

```
sudo mount -o loop my.iso /tmp/my_dir
```

If I run `ls -l` command I get

```
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 2048 abr 19 23:16 my_dyr
```

Perfect.

But I have come to an issue with the **Hiren's Boot ISO**. *I can mount it* using the above command, but then the `/tmp/my_dir` **is unaccesible**! Running `ls -l` again i get

```
drwx------ 3 nobody  401 2048 nov  7  2012 my_dir
```

I can't `chmod` or `chown` either.

I really don't know what is special about this particular ISO, or if is a feature of some ISOS I don't know about. Maybe somebody can enlighten me.

Thanks.

Comment: chamoro Please type `mount` command after you've mounted Hiren's Boot ISO to check what the filesystem is set for mounted iso. I assume that this iso is mounted as iso9660 but you should force to mount this iso as UDF.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk issuing the command `sudo mount -t udf -o loop Hirens.BootCD.15.2.iso /tmp/isos_mount_dir/` I get `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error`

Comment: What is the output of `file Hirens.BootCD.15.2.iso`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `Hirens.BootCD.15.2.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'HBCD 15.2' (bootable)`

Comment: @guillermochamorro try to add `nojoliet,unhide` options when you will mount.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk No luck. The thing is that I can mount it with the GUI, I copied the mount parameters, changed the folder to one in my home, but no difference

Comment: If I check `/etc/mtab` for the GUI mount I get `ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmode=500,fmode=400 0 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it, adding the `user id` and `group id`:

```
sudo mount -ro uid=1000,gid=1000 Hirens.BootCD.15.2.iso ~/Tmp/foo/
```